# How to lock user out on too many attempts to login?

Tags: security, authentication, flask

I want to lock out someone excessively failing log ins. For example, on the 5th incorrect login attempt, the person will be locked out from logging in again for 10 minutes.

I am considering keeping track of the user's IP address and locking them out if the IP address exceeds 5 attempts in the span of 10 minutes. Is there a library perhaps that could take care of this? What is the best way to do this? I am using flask.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in your program, every time you press a `submit` *button*, your browser ***calls the URL associated with that form***; that URL is routed to your `login()` **handler function**, which runs from the start, isn't it? . The function itself *has no memory of previous calls* (for obvious reasons since otherwise it would count **ALL** login attempts of **ALL** users). The form is populated from the data sent in the submit request, which is sent automatically to the form instantation by the `flask-wtf` library.

You need to store that count somewhere between `calls`. A good place to do that is in a `cookie` :

Flask includes the [sessions API](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make this simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately, a cookie is a very bad place to store login attempts in order to prevent brute forcing, as the cookie is stored client side with the browser, and can be easily deleted. A better place would be the database, maybe another field in the user table or similar.

Comment: you're right; I have also thought about this but I decided to write down the easiest solution, thanks for the fix. At this point, consider using @J.G. solution.